# How to subtract current time from a target time?

Tags: ios, swift

I figured out how to display the live current time in "hh:mm:ss" (code below). I want the label to display the time left until a specific target time, like a countdown. I want it to count down until e.g. 3pm each day and then start over. I know I need to subtract my target time from the current time but I don't know how to do that.

(I am new to programming)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!

var timer = Timer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

getCurrentTime()
    }
private func getCurrentTime() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector:#selector(self.currentTime) , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func currentTime() {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss"

    Label.text = formatter.string(from: Date())

}


}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. *"(I am new to programming)"* --- I suggest you do a google search for `swift working with dates and times` and read a couple articles.

Answer (score 1):

Use `timeIntervalSince` to find TimeInterval between two dates. Like below

```
let secondsBetween: TimeInterval = targetDate.timeIntervalSince(currentDate)
self.counter = Int(secondsBetween)
func timerAction() {
        counter -= 1
        label.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(counter))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! What type should targetDate be? I am also getting an error message for timeString: "Use of unresolved identifier 'timeString' "

Comment: timestring is custom function to convert remaining time in "hh:mm:ss"  format so you need to write your logic there instead of timestring function. target date is Date type.